# How to add TemplateField programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

please consider this code:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="linkmodel" Text='<%#Eval("MenuItem") %>' 
                         CommandName='<%#Eval("CommandName") %>'
                         OnCommand="linkmodel_Click" 
                         OnClientClick="return confirm('Are You Sure')">
         </asp:LinkButton>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

How to add this column programmatically using C#?

thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This might help to get started:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    { 
        var linkField = new TemplateField();
        linkField.ItemTemplate = new LinkColumn();
        GridView1.Columns.Add(linkField);
    }
}


class LinkColumn : ITemplate
{
    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
        link.ID = "linkmodel";
        container.Controls.Add(link);
    }
}
```

**But**:

> Although you can dynamically add fields to a data-bound control, it is
>   **strongly recommended** that fields be statically declared and then shown
>   or hidden, as appropriate. Statically declaring all your fields
>   reduces the size of the view state for the parent data-bound control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.templatefield.aspx

Comment: thanks but how I can pass attributes? like `Text,CommandName,OnClientClick`

Comment: @Kerezo: A **template** does only define the controls it does not define the content. So you could use `FindControl("linkmodel")` in [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) to get the reference to the linkbutton. Then you can set properties like `Text` according to the row's [`DataItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx) property.

Comment: If you follow the last link you'll find the answer:
`link.DataBinding += new EventHandler(link_DataBinding);
private void link_DataBinding(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
      LinkButton l = (LinkButton )sender;
      GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)l.NamingContainer;
      l.Text = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, "field").ToString();
}`

Comment: The view state size increases if controls are added in Page_Load. It's better to add fields in GridView1_Init.