# Asp.Net Grid view with Dynamically generated TemplateField Columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Grid view,its first three columns are created manually and i want to add remaining columns dynamically in code behind,Also the remaining columns must   contain text boxes in it.How can i do this?
I tried the code in the following link:
[How to add TemplateField programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581088/how-to-add-templatefield-programmatically)
By using this i can add text boxes in the columns,but can't find a way to access the values in Text Boxes

```
 public class AddTemplateToGridView : ITemplate
{
    ListItemType _type;
    string _colName,status;
    int i = 0;


public AddTemplateToGridView(ListItemType type, string colname,string stat)
    {
        _type = type;

        _colName = colname;
        status = stat;
    }
    public AddTemplateToGridView()
    {

    }
    void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        switch (_type)
        { 

            case ListItemType.Item:
                TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                txt.ID =id;
                if (status == "havevalue")
                {
                    txt.DataBinding += new EventHandler(ht_DataBinding);
                }

                container.Controls.Add(txt);
                break;
        }

    }
```

This is my code for adding text boxes.how can i add different ids for each text boxes? And i found that the id will lost when i click another button,Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: _"remaining columns must text contain text boxes"_?? Can you show your current grid? I think this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581088/how-to-add-templatefield-programmatically

Comment: When you want to get the values of text box in gridview, Just do loop with the Number of rows in the gridview. By use the following code to get value, `string Txt= (TextBox)gridViewID.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("TextboxID").Text;`

Comment: my need is to get the value of each textbox in a button click,can i get the value in buttonclick?

Comment: Sir when i use this code .Text shows error.Then i edit the code as TextBox  Txt = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].FindControl("text"); Then the Txt get null value

Comment: is "text" your Textbox id? If it returns null means, there is no Textbox in grid with id "text"

Comment: no,id is txt.ID =id; and i initialized string id="text"; in my class

Comment: sir is there any another way to add different ids to each text boxes?

Comment: Sir i am not sure but i think the cause of returning null is ,the id will lost on page rendering when button click.When i try to access it before any other events(in the same button click event that i load grid view) it shows an error "text boxes having same ids are found"

Comment: yes you can, In your case you are adding the rows one by one right? if it is, then use the row count to set incremented ids for textbox. `id=GridView1.Rows.count;` then`txt.ID=id;`

Comment: mam, you can check the id of the textbox by right click the textbox in page, then click inspect element. There you can see your Textbox ID.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the unique id you can with DataItemIndex:

```
private void tb_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
        GridViewRow container = (GridViewRow)tb.NamingContainer;

        object dataValue = DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, columnName, GetFormat());
        if (dataValue != DBNull.Value)
            tb.Text = dataValue.ToString();

        tb.ID = columnName + container.DataItemIndex;
    }
```