# bind dynamic columns template field in gridview from code behind C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have stored proc using pivot(dynamic query) that will return dynamic columns. Like

```
ItemId   A         B              c
------   --        --            --
1        A_Value1   B_Value1     C_Value1
16       A_Value2   B_Value2     C_Value2
```

Here A,B,C are dynamic columns . Sometime A only occur or A,B,C,D,E, etc because its pivot table.
Then,
 I will bind that result in gridview. 
My requirement is, I want to bind that result gridview's template field with link button. Because I want to do rowcommand event for each column.
My command argument should be like this for column C

```
CommandArgument = ColumnName+","+ItemID_Value;
```

i.e 
 `CommandArgument = "A,16";`

How to do this . pls help.

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns could create the GridView columns for you but they would be BoundFields. So you may have to create your fields manually in code-behind (by adding the TemplateFields to the Columns property of the GridView according to the content of your DataView). As for the LinkButtons, I am not sure where you want them. On each data item (e.g. A_Value1)? Or only on the ItemId column?

Comment: yes I want link button for each data item. means A_Value1 is link button , B_Value1 is link btn, all columns values are link button except itemID column.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581088/how-to-add-templatefield-programmatically

Comment: @ConnorsFan I will check and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You have already answer :)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="A">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkModify" Text="Edit" CommandName="MyCommand">
       </asp:LinkButton>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And `OnRowDataBound` (or directly in aspx)

```
MyClass item = e.Row.DataItem as MyClass;
LinkButton lnk = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkModify");
lnk.CommandArgument = "A," + item.Id;
```

EDIT: sorry i read now that they are dinamic columns. 
Two solutions:

1. First of all you need to have always all columns. Then you can write code as above but you have dynamic `HeaderText` and `CommandArgument` can read HeaderText (or index of relative columns). Then you can use `Visible` on `LinkButton` if a column is not present.
2. if you don't know columns number, you can build your data structure and the use `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` to bind data.

If you don't need pagination, you can use nested Repeater (one for columns ABCDE, one for rows).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, i edited the answer. Can you update your question adding data /class structure of your items?

Comment: This is like autogenerateColumns=true, but all values are like link btn except item_id column. when we click that link btn i need to pass two values(column name and respective ItemID  ) to stored proc procB.

Comment: You can concatenate two fields of your databound item