# Making a dynamic Gridview table in which the column need to filled using loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Right now I have a Gridview with following code;

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="grdInspStra" ID="grdInspStra" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCreated="grdInspStra_RowCreated">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="grdItemEven" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Zone Code" ItemStyle-CssClass="grdItemCenter">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblZone" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ZoneCode")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Group Code" ItemStyle-CssClass="grdItemCenter">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblGroup" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GroupCode")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Component Code" ItemStyle-CssClass="grdItemCenter">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblComp" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ComponentCode")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Component Tag No." ItemStyle-CssClass="grdItemCenter">
           <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCompTagNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ComponentTagRef")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Risk Category" ItemStyle-CssClass="grdItemCenter">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRiskCat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RiskCategory")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Proposed Interval" ItemStyle-CssClass="grdItemCenter">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblInterval" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProposedInterval")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Latest Date" ItemStyle-CssClass="grdItemCenter">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblDateLatest" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateLI")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="H1" ItemStyle-CssClass="grdItemCenter">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblFirstHalf0" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstHalf0")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="H2" ItemStyle-CssClass="grdItemCenter">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblSecondHalf0" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SecondHalf0")%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

However I try to eliminate this code;

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="H1" ItemStyle-CssClass="grdItemCenter">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFirstHalf0" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstHalf0")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="H2" ItemStyle-CssClass="grdItemCenter">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblSecondHalf0" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SecondHalf0")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This is because the column named `H1` and `H2` will need to be repeated from 0 => 30 so that, at the end of code the label name become;

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFirstHalf30" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstHalf30")%>'></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblSecondHal30" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SecondHalf30")%>'></asp:Label>
```

I manage to create the column using in Page_Load;

```
TemplateField tfield;
for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
{
    tfield = new TemplateField();
    tfield.HeaderText = "H1";
    grdInspStra.Columns.Add(tfield);

    tfield = new TemplateField();
    tfield.HeaderText = "H2";
    grdInspStra.Columns.Add(tfield);
 }
```

However I don't have any idea how to put the label and bind the data from SQL server using C#.

I try to us example from [How to add TemplateField programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581088/how-to-add-templatefield-programmatically) but I get is wrong value because it simply just doesnt loop. (Noted that I just testing to put data from server to `H2` only)

What I try is;

```
TemplateField tfield;
for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
{
    tfield = new TemplateField();
    tfield.HeaderText = "H1";
    tfield.ItemStyle.CssClass = "grdItemCenter";
    grdInspStra.Columns.Add(tfield);

    tfield = new TemplateField();
    tfield.HeaderText = "H2";
    tfield.ItemStyle.CssClass = "grdItemCenter";
    tfield.ItemTemplate = new LabelColumn();
    grdInspStra.Columns.Add(tfield);
}

class LabelColumn : ITemplate
{
    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.ID = "lblSecondHalf";
        label.DataBinding += new EventHandler(label_DataBinding);
        container.Controls.Add(label);
    }

    private void label_DataBinding(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label label = (Label)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)label.NamingContainer;
        label.Text = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, "SecondHalf0").ToString();
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After afternoon break I manage to solve this question.

In `class LabelColumn : ITemplate` just add `int i`, example;

```
class LabelColumn : ITemplate
{
    int i;

    public LabelColumn(int i)
    {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.ID = "lblSecondHalf" + i;
        label.DataBinding += new EventHandler(label_DataBinding);
        container.Controls.Add(label);
    }

    private void label_DataBinding(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label label = (Label)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)label.NamingContainer;
        label.Text = DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, "SecondHalf" + i).ToString();
    }
}
```