# ASP.NET GridView to Excel with Booleans

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, gridview, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP.NET Entity Framework and I have an export to excel method, it works, but I have one problem. I have booleans in my data and in my excel spreadsheet the booleans do not return, its just empty. I am expecting to print out yes or no. How can I accomplish this?

Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult ExportData()
{
    GridView gv = new GridView();
    gv.DataSource = db.Data.ToList().Where(model => model.closed == false);
    gv.DataBind();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=IssueTracking.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gv.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");

}
```

Or actually as I am only getting data that is false, all the rows for closed could return No

Comment: it better to use `EPPlus` http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: Can you show how your Boolean field is mapped in Gridview from ASPX page?

Comment: I dont have ASPX pages, this is MVC 5

Comment: I wonder how you got GridView control in MVC5??

Comment: ahhh I realize now you are doing a convoluted process just to create Excel... don't do this :)

Comment: How else do I export my data to excel @techspider ?

Answer (score 0):

Exporting from GridView takes all content from the actual rendered content. This will not work unless you define a `TemplateField` in `GridView` which outputs `Yes` or `No`.  An equivalent `GridView` template field will look like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-Width="30">
    <ItemTemplate><%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("IsActive").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Provided you are using MVC, it is not a preferred way to achieve this task.  There is always difference between *getting it done* and *getting it done in the right way*.

You have to add the fields programmatically, if you still want to go this way.

Creating a `BoundField` dynamically

```
BoundField boundField = new BoundField();
boundField.HeaderText = "HeaderText";
boundField.DataField = "FiledToBeMapped"
gv.Columns.Add(boundField);
```

Creating a `TemplateField` dynamically

```
var templateField = new TemplateField();
templateField .ItemTemplate = new LinkColumn();
gv.Columns.Add(templateField);
```

For more details, use this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1683126.aspx?BoundField%20to%20TemplateField%20with%20LinkButton%20in%20gridview%20code%20behind), this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13462/How-to-create-template-columns-dynamically-in-a-gr) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581088/how-to-add-templatefield-programmatically).

Comment: This makes no sense to me :(