# Add a checkboxes column to a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that displays data coming from an SQL data source (stored procedure) and I want to add a checkboxex column to it, here is my code:

```js
TemplateField field = new TemplateField();
field.HeaderText = "Exporter ?";
gv.Columns.Add(field);
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
cb.Visible = true;
```

The problem is that I don't know how to add a checkbox to the TemplateField that I added to my gridview columns.

Comment: look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581088/how-to-add-templatefield-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the code below into the `GridView` **Columns**.

```
<asp:templatefield HeaderText="Check Box">
    <itemtemplate>
        <asp:checkbox ID="cb" runat="server"></asp:checkbox>
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:templatefield>
```

Comment: Thanks, I also would like the column containing checkboxes to be invisible by default the programmatically make it visible at runtime, I don't know how to do the second part since I can't add an ID attribute to the templatefield or the itemtemplate tags?

Comment: I believe **Gounder** have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

1) Add below code to GridView columns.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CheckBoxColumn" Visible="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="checkBox" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>                   
            </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

2) Make checkbox column visible dynamically by adding **OnRowDataBound** event or just looping through GridView.Rows

```
int indexOfCBColumn = 0;
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   e.Row.Cells[indexOfCBColumn].Visible = true;
}



foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) {
   if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
      row.Cells[indexOfCBColumn].Visible = true;
   }
}
```

Thanks!!